# In a Listbox change the color of textbox when checking a checkbox c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, listboxitem

I have a listbox with 3 buttons, 2 textboxes and a checkbox in each element.

I would like for the buttons and txtboxes to change properties(Color/or other) when i check the checkbox.

Hope someone can help me :)

Thankyou for your answer...

```
        <!-- LISTBOX -->
        <ListBox Name="lstBoxInfoWindow" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="Black" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="5,1.2,4.6,-0.4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property=""
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Button Name="btnPackageVersion" Content ="Package version" Click="btnPackageVersion_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,10,0">

                        </Button>
                        <Button Name="btnFilterPath" Content ="Filter path" Click="btnFilterpath_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="txtBlkPath" Text="{Binding path, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="10" Width="500" Height="20" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>

                        <Button Name="btnFilterfile" Content="Filter file" Click="btnFilterfile_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="txtBlkFile" Text="{Binding file, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="10" Width="150" Height="20" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>

                        <CheckBox Name="chkBxKill" Content="Kill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsChecked="{Binding keepKill.kill, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,0,5,0" Checked="chkBxKill_Checked"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `DataTrigger` defined in the `DataTemplate`.

The following example sets the `Backgound` of the button to red when the `CheckBox` is checked:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    ...

    <Button Name="btnFilterfile" />    
    <CheckBox Name="chkBxKill" />
  </StackPanel>

  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chkBxKill, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
      <Setter TargetName="btnFilterfile" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: TY for your answer. First i need to say, Im a total newb, so i might say something stupid!. Ive implemented your suggestion, and it seems that there is no "Background" property on the button. There is something called TextElement.FontWeight which i give the value Extralight. But it does not show in the listbox.

Comment: `<DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chkBxKill, Path=IsChecked}">
                            <Setter TargetName="btnFilterfile" Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="ExtraLight"/>
`

Comment: Make sure you are using the proper Button from the proper namespace. It must be `System.Windows.Controls.Button` then you will get the Background property. TextElement.FontWeight does not apply to Button. Not sure what namespace you are using (Windows.UI.XAML - UWP?)

Comment: After reviewing the code I found that the `Value="True"` attribute is missing on the `DataTrigger`. I have added it. Now it should work. I wrote this code in the edit box (no compiler support), so sorry for that.

Comment: Oh dont be im just glad to get help :) TY IT WORKED :) Great man.